# react-native-pages scrollToPage is not a function

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-pages

I'm using react-native-pages to allow the user to swipe between screens, but I need to also swipe between screens programmatically.

I've tried using the scrollToPage method, 1. but I'm not sure how to properly implement it and 2. I am getting an error that says it is not a function.

I'm defining a reference like this:

```
this.pages = React.createRef();
```

Then in the renderer:

```
<Pages indicatorColor={'green'} indicatorOpacity={0.3} indicatorPosition={"bottom"} ref={ref => { this.pages = ref; }} >
```

Then calling:
`this.pages.scollToPage(2)`
in a method after rendering

Any advice on how to get this to work would be great

Comment: `react-native-pages` does not have reference properties.

Comment: How can the scrollToPage method be called then?

Comment: I have posted a definition for the `scrollToPage` function.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Just Like This]

1. define your ref(also you can set it in your constructor() function)
2. link the ref with your Pages Tag (ref={this.refblablabla})
3. in your current class, you can do whatever you want when you need the ref.(do not forget the ref.current is object you want not the ref its self)

if you need a snap of code, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of the `scrollToPage` function.

```js
scrollToPage(page, animated = true) {
    let { horizontal } = this.props;
    let { [horizontal? 'width' : 'height']: base } = this.state;

    if (animated) {
      this.scrollState = 1;
    }

    if (this.mounted && this.scroll) {
      this.scroll.scrollTo({
        [horizontal? 'x' : 'y']: page * base,
        animated,
      });
    }
  }
```